# Bootstrap 4 Popover not working with Safari

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-popover

I am trying to get a popover to show on hover. It is working in all browsers *except* Safari. Absolutely nothing happens in Safari. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="my-class" data-toggle="popover">
    ...
</div>
```

Here is the html that is listening for the popover:

```
$(function () {

$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    trigger: 'hover',
    placement: 'top',
    html: true,
    title: function () {
        return $('.qtip .title', $(this)).html();
    },
    content: function () {
        return $('.qtip .content', $(this)).html();
    }
});  

});
```

Safari isn't seeing the hover at all in the console. I'm not sure if I've missed an obvious step or what I've done incorrectly. Thank you for any suggestions!

**EDIT**

I am using this on the same page and it is working in all browsers.

```
$('[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function (event) {
     ...
});
```

Comment: This link might help you: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3687

Comment: Thanks Aniket - it seems like that is all angular-ui/angular bootstrap. I'm running straight jQuery + BS. Is there a spot in that page in particular that you think can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to understand the difference between `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` and `bootstrap.min.js`

> bootstrap.bundle.js which contains Popper.js in order for popovers to work!

If you include the popper and other libraries (for whatever reasons) in addition to the `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` file, Safari and Edge will complain. At that point they throw a generic error up the chain and js just gives up -- causing the popover to not work.

Hope this helps someone else!